# How to know if a calendar from Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ekeventstore

I have already fetch calendars from EKEventStore ,so is there a way to know if a calendar is from Facebook or not like the picture below.

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- get the description string from the calendar object.
- in this string there is "account=Facebook" substring.

So you have to split the description string and get the "account" substring and read the value  from there